# Replace $ sign in all document

Tags: javascript, html, replace

How to replace all '$' characters in my page anywhere when page is ON load. $ can come multiple times in, So we need to replace all '$' with the '+'. Here's what I have:

MY HTML:

```
<div>$a sa d $0.12354



        <select name="" id="">
            <option value="">My service price $1.79 per 1000 </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT:

```
function nativeSelector() {
              var elements = document.querySelectorAll("body, body *");
              var results = [];
              var child;
              for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                  child = elements[i].childNodes[0];
                  if(elements[i].hasChildNodes() && child.nodeType == 3) {
                      results.push(child);
                  }
              }
              return results;
          }

          var textnodes = nativeSelector(),
          _nv;
          for (var i = 0, len = textnodes.length; i<len; i++){
              _nv = textnodes[i].nodeValue;
              textnodes[i].nodeValue = _nv.replace(/$/g,'€');
          }
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the `$` in the regular expression

Comment: can you point me where ?

Comment: Your regular expression is the first parameter you passed to `.replace`. You forgot to escape the `$` in it.

Comment: i have put $ in replace(/$/g,'€') but nothing happens. can you give me jsfiddle example

Comment: See https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html - `$` matches the beginning of the line in a regular expression, so you need to escape it

Comment: just add "\" before $ sign in replace funtion

 _nv.replace(/\$/g,'€');